# Minimum volume too loud, can't set it any lower

Tags: soundcloud

Is there any way to lower the volume in SoundCloud below minimum?
I've noticed that you can't set exact sound volume in soundcloud, I believe it goes like 100>90>....30>20>10>0, but I need it about ~6%.

I feel like I will lose my ears on 10% (I have very powerful system that's always on 100%, can't change that.. You don't want to know how it sounds at 100% in soundcloud). Have no problems with other players and pages.

Comment: there's your system’s sound output config that should be between SoundCloud and your audio system that you can't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an HTML5 widget, yes you can.

Check out the API playground [here](https://w.soundcloud.com/player/api_playground.html).

Using the `setVolume()` function, you can set the volume to any int value between 0 and 100.  Setting the value to 6 should give you the results you desire.

Check out the API reference for more details on how to use this function:
https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/html5-widget#methods

On the other hand, this is more of a hardware configuration issue/question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

In Chrome, you can install an EQ extension such as [this one](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ears-bass-boost-eq-any-au/nfdfiepdkbnoanddpianalelglmfooik/related?hl=en).

Then in your Soundcloud tab, open the EQ extension and drag the white line downwards lowering the volume of that tab alone.

I wanted to listen to Soundcloud while watching Lynda.com courses, but the quietest Soundcloud volume was still overpowering.

Hope this helps someone!